# Problems with mongodb, toggle on/off code, Discord.js

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

```
const client = require("../../index");
const { ChatInputCommandInteraction, Discord } = require('discord.js');
const db = require("../../models/salvage/command");
const { loadCommands } = require("../../Handlers/commandHandler");
const schema = require('../../models/salvage/command')

module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate1",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {ChatInputCommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
        async execute(interaction, client, guild) { 
        if(!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        const check = await db.findOne({ Guild: guild.message.id })
            if(check) {
                if(check.Cmds.includes(interaction.commandName)) return interaction.reply({content: "Comando desactivado!"})
                command.execute(interaction, client);
            } else {
                command.execute(interaction, client);
            }

        }
   }
```

I have finished with the toggle on/off code (activate deactivate commands), but I have a problem, when deactivating a command it only sends a message that it deactivated but it is not like that, since if I put it again it sends it to me again, try everything, see in forums, youtube and nothing. I have the MongoDB connected to my bot perfectly, I really don't know what to do and I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: can you show the code where you activate/deactivate the command?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, can you elaborate on what you are trying to get?

Comment: @itzJOH_ Disabled = https://ibb.co/TPszDg7
Enabled =https://ibb.co/Tk5ZgBM

Comment: @Dan What I want to achieve with this is to disable a command with MongoDB, but, after finishing the code for a while, it doesn't disable me, I don't know what kind of error it is.

Comment: @E4v4ef your code is really messed up... in your disable/enable commands you are trying to find your db document by `interactin.guild.cmd`, which will be undefined ([read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild)). please fix your logic and then ask questions.